Leveraging Qt models for nested data structures

Here is a simplified version of what I'm trying to achieve. For every Store that is added, one or more Departments can be added. For every Department that is added, one or more Employees can be added. Selecting a row in a list will update the lists to the right of it. E.g, selecting Sesame Street will update the Departments list to show all the Departments that belong to that Store. Selecting Clothing will update the Employees list to show all the Employees that belong to that Department.
This relationship is also demonstrated below (note that these will actually be classes, and capable of emitting signals when their data is changed internally, for example, from external sources):
struct Employee {
  std::string id;
  std::string name;
  double hourly_rate;
};

struct Department {
  std::string id;
  std::string name;
  int personCount;
  bool status;
  Employee* onShift;
  std::vector<Employee> employees;
};

struct Store {
  std::string id;
  std::string name;
  std::string address;
  std::vector<Department> departments;
};

On another tab, we have an aggregate list of all Departments across Stores, presenting live data, with a drop down list to select an on shift leader from the pool of Employees that belong to that Department.

As far as Qt models are concerned, I imagine there a several ways to approach this. I prefer to think of Qt models as only an interface between a view and data, rather than themselves being responsible for, or having ownership of said data.
I propose handing ownership of our data to a Manager class which also contains any subclassed models we create. For the configuration page, we have three QAbstractListModel subclasses for Stores, Departments and Employees. For the Departments and Employees models, we can pass a list pointer and call begin/endResetModel as needed to update the lists when items are selected.
For the All Departments page, we have an aggregateDepartments model also subclassed from QAbstractListModel. This would contain a list of pointers for all Departments across Stores. The On Shift Leader dropdown is a bit more tricky as we can't use a single model. I'm wondering in this case whether it would make more sense for Department to have its own instance of the Employee list which it can return to the QML delegate...
As you can see, we now have numerous models for what is a fairly basic data hierarchy. Synchronisation between models could become an issue, so the underlying data should only be modified via the Manager class, which can then orchestrate updating of the models.
Have I described a worthy approach to the problem or have I created a convoluted mess? I can't really think of a better way

the idea of a manager sounds correct, but the onShift field is worrying, once you start adding and removing items this will easily become a dangling pointer or point to the wrong object, as vector doesn't provide a stable pointer guarantee. replace it with the id instead of a pointer.

Sorry but I don't really understand what you want to know. Are you asking if your approach is valid and/or we could suggest further alternatives? In that case, sorry but that's basically asking for opinion, and such questions are considered off topic on SO.

@AhmedAEK, thanks. Does the general model design sound sensible to you?

@musicamante, I was mostly asking if the approach is valid. As in, does it align with Qt's model paradigm. I don't think that is so subjective as to disqualify the question from SO.

You may want to check using QSqlQueryModel. For your situation, you can use three tables and QSqlQueryModel.

@19172281 Well, like any programming paradigm, it's not an absolute rule that has to be followed strictly, nor it dictates a pattern that, if not completely adherent to its definitions, would become "wrong". A programming pattern or paradigm is fundamentally a set of guidelines that help [to define] development, and any of its "rules", as any rule, can be bent without automatically invalidating the choice of this or that pattern, nor making the code "bad" in principle. If it works, and the reasoning behind its implementation makes sense, nobody can tell you that it's wrong. Besides, the »

@19172281 » Qt model/view paradigm is fundamentally a higher level description of the common data model they use in their API, it doesn't tell the programmer how to completely lay out and manage the whole data model of their programs. If your program requires a complex structure of models, including those that are abstract and rely on other ones, there is absolutely nothing wrong or invalid in that. Qt itself does that with some of its models, such as the proxy models, the QSqlRelationalTableModel or the QConcatenateTablesProxyModel (which doesn't even inherit from QAbstractProxyModel). »

@19172281 » So, the only thing you may need to consider is the validity with the QAbstractItemModel API (which you can check with QAbstractItemModelTester within the appropriate context), so that you can ensure that it conforms with what other model/view classes would expect (views, proxy models and related classes such as QDataWidgetMapper or QML based ones). If your case requires a complex model structure, then that's what you probably need: ensure that your approach makes sense and works well, before worrying too much about whether it is "compliant" or "aligned" with some paradigm.

@musicamante, that's certainly reassuring. I just wanted to make sure that my suggested approach wasn't a glaring violation of any Qt model principles or best practices. It sounds like that isn't the case.
